# UNIX - Sed Command to print Occurrence between lines

Tags: unix, sed

```
sed '/Storage/,/Design/p' sample.txt
```

The above helps to print the lines between `Storage` and `Design`.

My question is  how to get the second occurrence of the above sed command ?

My file has many Storage - Design pattern matches, but I want to take second occurrence paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` prints second section:

```
cat file
start
1 data
end
not this
start
2 more data
end
not here
```

```
awk '/start/ {f=1;a++} f && a==2; /end/ {f=0}' file
start
2 more data
end
```

---

It the file has more `start` than `end` this counts group of `start/end`

```
cat file
start
start
1 data
end
not this
start
2 more data
end
not here
```

```
awk '/start/ {f=1} f && a==1; /end/ {if (f) a++;f=0}' file
start
2 more data
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ne '$count++ if /start/; print if /start/ .. /end/ and 2 == $count'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/Storage/,/Design/{x;/./{x;p;x};x;/Design/h}' file
```

As @jotne has pointed out to cease after the second occurence:

```
sed -n '/Storage/,/Design/{x;/./{x;p;/Design/q;x};x;/Design/h}' file
```

Comment: This prints all section from second, not only second section.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/Storage/,/Design/ H
/Design/ {
    g
    s/\(.*Storage\)\{2\}/Storage/
    t print
    b
 : print
    p
    q
    }' YourFile
```

Keep all Storage section in buffer, when buffer is feeded with 2 Storage, remove first, print section and quit. I use the `\{2\}` to easily change the selected occurence (sed limitation is 255 if i remeber well but is easy to workaround)